# eclipse not accepting set heap size in eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse, performance-testing, rpt, rational-performance-test

I am using IBM rational performance tester with eclipse and have set “show heap status” in **windows>preferences>general** in eclipse. But when I run my application/performance test it shows java heap space error.

My eclipse.ini is :

```
-vm

C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe

-startup

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar

-install

C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP

--launcher.library

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222

-vmargs=-Xmx1500m

-Xquickstart

-Xms40m

-Xgcpolicy:gencon

-Xscmx48m

-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u

-Xmx1947m

-Xjit:disableValueProfiling
```

But when I checked the heap status in status bar of eclipse as shown in following figure:

[image]

It shows “**max:512M**” but in eclipse.ini I have set it to **“-Xmx1947m**” as shown in above eclipse file.

Can anyone please tell me why it is showing **max:512M** in heap status bar in eclipse when I have set it to **1947**M?

Comment: Can you try remove the first Xmx in the vmargs line and then try again?

Answer (score 1):

`-vmargs=-Xmx1500m` is not a valid entry in the eclipse.ini.

`-vmargs` must be on a line by itself or it will not be recognized. Since the `-vmargs` line is not correct all the VM arguments are being ignored.

Comment: But on one system with same eclipse.ini contents, the heap status bar in eclipse is showing max heap size according to this ini file as max:1947M (i.e. accepting the settings of eclipse.ini) but on another system of my collegue with same eclipse.ini file contents it is not accepting the the max heap size and showing max:512M. why so